# how to get the column size of a table in sybase 2

Tags: sybase

In sybase central is there a query to see the column length as well as the column type of a table like VARCHAR(255), VARCHAR(500)...?

i've tried this query

```
SELECT syscolumns.name, systypes.name FROM sysobjects 
JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
JOIN systypes ON systypes.type = syscolumns.type AND systypes.usertype=  syscolumns.usertype
WHERE sysobjects.name LIKE 'table_name'
```

but i only have the column type (VARCHAR).

Answer (score 2):

You should use the columns 'length', 'prec' or 'scale' from syscolumns, depending on the datatype.